# Knockout.js containerless "foreach" not working with <table>

Tags: syntax, knockout.js

This code throws the error (in Chrome): "Cannot find closing comment tag to match: ko foreach: MyPlans":

```
<table>
  <!-- ko foreach: MyPlans -->
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

If I use a list instead, everything works:

```
<ul>
  <!-- ko foreach: MyPlans -->
    <li>
      Test
    </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

I would like to use the containerless foreach with a table. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is related to the fact that browsers insert `tbody` tags automatically, which creates a mismatch in the comments.  The rendered output will look like:

```
<table>
  <!-- ko foreach: MyPlans -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Steve did put some work into trying to correct mismatched tags in KO, but the easiest thing for you to do is either add the `tbody` yourself or add the `tbody` and put your binding on it.

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: MyPlans">
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It is legal for a table to have multiple `tbody` tags, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This clears things up quite a bit. I'll be sure to check the actual markup more carefully going forward.

Comment: As RP mentions it's legal to have multiple `tbody` tags. It's useful to group rows, [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) is more information.