# Knockout.js repeat rows in table for nested model / containerless "foreach" inside table

Tags: knockout.js

I’m building an application to track orders of tailor made products. Each product can have many custom details. The screen to add products to an order and customize each one should look like this:

```
<button>+</button><!-- "Add new product line" button -->
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Producto</th><!-- The product category or type -->
            <th>Modelo</th><!-- The product -->
            <th>Cantidad</th><!-- Quantity -->
            <th>Unitario</th><!-- Unit Price -->
            <th>Mano de Obra</th><!-- The price of the product itself -->
            <th>Genero</th><!-- The price of the customization -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="producto"><!-- Product line -->
            <td><button>-</button></td><!-- "Remove" button, should remove the product and it's customizations -->
            <td><select>Producto</select></td><!-- Choose category -->
            <td><select>Modelo</select></td><!-- Choose product -->
            <td><input type="text" class="cantidad" /></td><!-- Enter quantity -->
            <td><input type="text" class="unitario" /></td><!-- Enter unit price -->
            <td>$ <span class="mano_obra"></span></td><!-- Line total. The product lines calculates on this column -->
            <td><button>+</button></td><!-- "Add customization" button. Should add a line like the next <tr> -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="genero"><!-- Customization line -->
            <td><button>-</button></td><!-- "Remove" button, should remove only this customization line -->
            <td>Genero</td><!-- Fixed text -->
            <td><input type="text" class="genero" /></td><!-- Enter customization description -->
            <td><input type="text" class="cantidad" /></td><!-- Enter quantity -->
            <td><input type="text" class="unitario" /></td><!-- Enter unit price -->
            <td>&nbsp;</td><!-- On customizations, this column is empty -->
            <td>$ <span class="genero"></span></td><!-- Line total. The customizations calculates on this column -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="genero">
            <!-- Another customization for the first product -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="genero">
            <!-- Another one -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="producto">
            <!-- A different product -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="genero">
            <!-- The new product customization -->
        </tr>
        <!-- (etc) -->
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">Subtotales</td><!-- Fixed text -->
            <td>$ <span class="subtotal_mano_obra"></span></td><!-- SUM of each line total, for products -->
            <td>$ <span class="subtotal_genero"></span></td><!-- SUM of each line total, for customizations -->
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I've tried to do this:

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: lineas_pedido'>
    <tr class="producto">
        <!-- All the bindings here works fine -->
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: generos -->
    <tr class="genero">
        <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

But after getting errors and looking, came to this: [Knockout.js containerless "foreach" not working with <table>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table)

So, I found this plugin: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat
And now my code looks like this:

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: lineas_pedido'>
    <tr class="producto">
        <!-- All the bindings here works fine -->
    </tr>
    <tr class="genero" data-bind="repeat: {foreach: generos, item: '$genero'}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My question is: Is there any way to avoid using the plugin, and accomplish the same result using native KO templating/bindings?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dXsyj/3/) is the jsfiddle, I've added a resource linking to my sample data (categories and products).

[Here](http://elboyero.oestedatos.com/deco.oestedatos.com/nuevo_pedido2.html) is the actual code on my testing host.

Also, I've used [this](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html) example as the start point.

Comment: if would be easier for people to help if you post a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Maybe you can repro off of this one: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dXsyj/.  I am interested to see where the errors were coming from that you were getting when you used a containerless foreach inside of the tbody.

Comment: The example you provided works great, so I think my error is somewhere else. You can see the code in the updated version and in my site. Hope you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've spotted 3 errors in your fiddle. pretty sure I didn't break any logic but it'd be easier if I knew spanish :)
Updated fiddle with fixes here: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/cxLRs/

1. `data-bind` is not supposed to appear here: `<!-- ko data-bind='foreach: generos' -->`
2. You had a "`click: remover`" binding which called `LineaGenero.remover`, which expects a `LineaPedido` which is the parent to remove from. But the actual argument was the current `LineaGenero`, not its parent. The correct approach here is the same as you did with the binding "`click: $parent.removerLinea`"
3. You had this line: `self.modelo(undefined);`
   which triggered the `self.modelo` subscription handler.
   There was no check in there for the `undefined` value, causing errors.