# knockout.js foreach repeats td element in table, but not the tr element

Tags: knockout.js, html-table

I have the following excerpt from a table that I'm using to display a lot of files retrieved from a server, using MVC 4 and the knockout.js library version 2.1.0.

```
    <tr data-bind="foreach: files, visible: (files() && files().length > 0)">
        <td data-bind="text: UploadPath" />
        <td data-bind="text: FileName" />
    </tr>
```

The data is being retrieved properly, however foreach is repeating the TD elements in the table and not the TR.  So if there are 100 files, there will be 200 columns in the table displayed to the user.  How do I make the TR element repeat foreach file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply put the "foreach" binding in the next (outer) element:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: files, ...">
    <tr>
        ...
```

You can also utilize a virtual element:

```
<!-- ko foreach: files -->
<tr>
    <td>
        ...
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I was leaning that way, but I didn't know if I wanted to next another table or not just to display the file data.  Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: And if you want the first TD element to be different from the rest?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a strange thing:

I was trying to use a containerless binding to repeat multiple table rows. KO complained that it couldn't find the closing /ko tag .

I had a table-header defined above the containerless binding. If I changed this to a standard table row everything worked as expected (except my header didn't have the required styling but I override that).

Hope this helps someone else struggling with this - it's only a workaround rather than a fix.

Comment: Ran into this same thing, solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8116017/423231

Comment: Thank you. I thought I'd researched it quite thoroughly but obviously not! It all makes sense now.