# Nested, containerless foreach in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout-2.0

I am having problems using containerless foreach nested inside a normal foreach binding within a table. The solution of adding your own `<tbody>` [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table?lq=1) does not work as seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLXJm/2/).

HTML

```
<table style="border: solid 1px black;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <!-- ko foreach: data -->
            <th data-bind="text: $data.name"></th>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: names">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td> 
            <!-- ko foreach: data -->
            <td data-bind="text: $data.abbr"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
var data = {
    names: [
        { name: 'Rick' },
        { name: 'Bob'},
        { name: 'Sue' },
    ],
    data:[
        { name: 'object1', abbr: 'obj1' },
        { name: 'object2', abbr: 'obj2' },
        { name: 'object3', abbr: 'obj3' },
        { name: 'object4', abbr: 'obj4' }
    ]
};

var model = function( data ){
    this.names = ko.observableArray( data.names );
    this.data = ko.observableArray( data.data );
}
ko.applyBindings( new model( data ) );
​
```

The table stops rendering after the first occurence of the `names.abbr` binding...am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use it `<!-- ko foreach: $parent.data -->` 
Because you are using it in a `foreach:names`, and names does not have any property with `name`, and you want to access its parent data so, use `$parent` to access its parent

Like

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: names">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td> 
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.data -->
        <td data-bind="text: $data.abbr"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->            
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLXJm/3/)**

Comment: LOL Duh! I slightly overlooked the fact that I was in a loop...thx