# Nested containerless foreach in tbody failing for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I'm having a bit of trouble getting some nested, containerless foreach bindings to work.  It works in grownup browsers, but not IE (8 OR 9).

The closest I could find was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table), but the root of that problem seems to be a lack of a `tbody` tag, which I have.  The error IE is giving is

> Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko foreach: seniors

Sorry for the wall of text, but below is my markup.

---

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: superGroups">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;" data-bind="text: superName() || 'No Super Set'" colspan="8">
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: seniors -->
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;" data-bind="text: seniorName() || 'No Senior Set'" colspan="7"></td>
    </tr>

        <!-- ko foreach: items -->

        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-bindX="text:superName"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bindX="text:seniorName"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:clientName"></span>
                <i class="icon-tags" data-bind="attr:{title: labels}, visible: labels"></i>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text:description"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="visible:superPayAmount">$<span data-bind="text:superPayAmount"></span></span>
                <span data-bind="visible:superPayAmount.length == 0">-</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="shortDate: superStartDate"></span> - <span data-bind="shortDate: superEndDate"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="visible:seniorPayAmount">$<span data-bind="text:seniorPayAmount"></span></span>
                <span data-bind="visible:!seniorPayAmount.length == 0">-</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="shortDate: seniorStartDate"></span> - <span data-bind="shortDate: seniorEndDate"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed closing `td` tag in the first `tr`:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;" data-bind="text: superName() || 'No Super Set'" colspan="8"></td>
</tr>
```