# Cannot find closing comment tag for Virtual Binding

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js

Hello I am have next part of mapping on client side,
then I added sub-array binding, I am starting to get error like
*Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko foreach: {data: $item.sub, as: 's'}*

```html
<tbody>
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: reportData, as: 'item'} -->
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: item.statDate">                        
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: item.newRegisteredUsers"></span>
            <table>
                <!-- ko foreach: {data: $item.sub, as: 's'} -->
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: s.name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: s.amount"></td>                                
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </table>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: item.text"></td>                           
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

what is the problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this everything? I don't see anything wrong with this particular snippet.

Comment: yes this is everything, may be i need to check....

Comment: yes nemesv you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that your browser is inserting a `tbody` element that wraps your inner table; you need to put it there explicitly (which accessibility guidelines say you should do in any case), with the `foreach` binding inside it:

```
        <span data-bind="text: newRegisteredUsers"></span>
        <table>
           <tbody>
            <!-- ko foreach: {$data.sub, as: 's'} -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: s.name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: s.amount"></td>                                
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
           </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: I always use an explicit <tbody> (now) and virtual bindings work great in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Reference:** [Knockout.js containerless "foreach" not working with <table>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table)

> This is related to the fact that browsers insert tbody tags
>   automatically, which creates a mismatch in the comments.

Try something like this instead, where I've moved the `foreach` into the `tbody` tag:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: reportData">    
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: statDate">                        
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: newRegisteredUsers"></span>
            <table>
                <!-- ko foreach: {$data.sub, as: 's'} -->
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: s.name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: s.amount"></td>                                
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </table>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: text"></td>                           
    </tr>
</tbody>
```