# How to bind value summernote editor in mvc using knockout js (MVVM)

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have sucessfull integration summernote editor in my mvc project but I can't get value form textarea.

i have use knockout (MVVM) structure.

```
<tbody data-bind='with:demo'>
     <textarea class="summernote" placeholder="Description" data-bind='value:   Description'></textarea>
</tbody>

var Demo = function (demo) {
var self = this;
self.Description = ko.observable(demo? demo.Description : '');
 }

var DemoViewModel = function () {
   var self = this;
   self.demo= ko.observable(new Demo());
 }

ko.applyBindings(new DemoViewModel ())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue relates to html and how browser will render it.

Your sample

```
<tbody data-bind='with:demo'>
    <textarea class="summernote" placeholder="Description" data-bind='value: Description'></textarea>
</tbody>
```

is rendered as. `tbody` is removed and knockout can't find `Description` binding

```
<textarea class="summernote" placeholder="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
```

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSerjo/fyQDE/23/) for more info. The issue is related to the fact that browsers insert tbody tags automatically, in your case removes the tag. Here's a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table), but with `foreach`

You can fix this in following manner

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="with:demo">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea placeholder="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSerjo/fyQDE/22/) for more info

Or add `div` tag ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSerjo/fyQDE/26/))

```
<div data-bind="with:demo">
    <tbody>
        <textarea placeholder="Description" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
    </tbody>
</div>
```

Note: `tbody` will be absent in the result html

Comment: Oh, interesting, didn't check that. @hardik probably has to combine your answer with mine to get on the right path... :)

Comment: And BTW: Your title edit is now a bit confusing... Sure that there's only this causality?

Comment: Yes, but reverted, here's similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table). A browser adds `tbody` automatically

Answer (score 5):

your best option is to create  custom binding like so

```
ko.bindingHandlers.summernote = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.html(value).summernote({
          callbacks:{
            onChange: function (contents) {
                valueAccessor()(contents);
            }
          }
        });
    }
};
```

and you can call it

```
<textarea  data-bind="summernote: Description"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Summernote, like many other "magic" JS libs, modifies your original html element and appends its own DOM structure when initializing the editor. This generally leads to problems when it comes to integration with JS frameworks that support and encourage data bindings via element attributes.

Regarding your code samples I guess you're initializing summernote with some jQuery code that looks similar to:

```
$('.summernote').summernote(...);
```

Now, since summernote creates an editor div element with the class name `note-editable`, you may programmatically set the *knockout* bindings by utilizing one of the callback parameters:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  oninit: function() {
    $('.note-editable').attr('data-bind','html: Description');
  }
});
```

Make sure that ko initialization takes place *after* the summernote initialization. Furthermore note that I replaced your *value* binding with a *html* binding. While I'm not familiar with knockout at all, I'm pretty sure you'll need it... See the [ko html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) for details.