# Knockoutjs Cannot find closing comment tag to match

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm getting the error Message:

> Cannot find closing comment tag to match: ko foreach: ($root.fetchSplitSchedule($index()))

Why?

Markup is below:

```html
<table class="table" data-bind="foreach:$root.weekDays">

    <!-- ko foreach: ($root.fetchSplitSchedule($index())) -->

    <tr>
        <td><strong data-bind="text:$data"></strong></td>
        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" 
            data-bind="clockPicker" 
            type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>to</td>
        <td><input class="form-control input-sm" 
            data-bind="clockPicker" 
            type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Split Hours</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- /ko -->

</table>
```

Using Knockout.js and jQuery. Can Knockout not handle nested loops?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout.js containerless "foreach" not working with <table>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table)

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, turns out you need tbody.

Comment: Knockout can handle nested loops, but not more than one per DOM nesting level.