# knockout.js - use a for binding within a with

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to do something like the html below, where I am using a `with binding` on the table, but within the table I want to do a `foreach loop` and access each element of the `foreach`.

When I do it this way, the `th` tags don't work, and it will only work if I remove the `with binding` from the html.

How can I get it to work (i.e. render the table headers with values 1, 2, 3)?

```
<table data-bind="with: myData">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" value=""></th>
        <!-- ko foreach: [1,2,3] -->
        <th data-bind="html: $data"></th>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <!-- other stuff here -->
</table>
```

Comment: May be <tbody> is missing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115896/knockout-js-containerless-foreach-not-working-with-table

Comment: A bit more of a clue would help. What does myData contain? And is it observable?

Comment: It is observable, but may be empty. If not empty, contains JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen, if `myData` is not an `observable` and `is empty`, without any value assigned to it.

I have tried your code [here](https://jsbin.com/solojuwuri/edit?html,js,output) and it is working properly.